# Returning a JSON response for passport-local when password or name is not correct

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am working on passport and passport-local for authentication and the problem I have now is that I want to return a JSON response to the frontend when the password or username is wrong but i keep getting the below from passport

[image]

my localstrategy

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const User = require("../models/user");
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

I am calling it on my route this way

```
router.post(
"/login",passport.authenticate("local", {
failureMessage: true,}),login);
```

Comment: could you share the functions User.authenticate() ?

Comment: The function is in-built after doing this `User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, options);`on the model